# Wiremock Stubs for multiple APIs

Tags: java, wiremock

I have been working on a `java standalone Wiremock server`, to mock external APIs.
I would like to reuse the server, to concentrate all my stubs in one place.

In the Spring cloud contracts, they use the package name to differentiate the stubs. I have tried something similar, I can package stubs in different jars but I don't know to reference the package on the client side.

```
 API A -> /get
 API B -> /get
```

What will be the recommended way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a separate URL for each package. If that is a unique string, then that should translate to a unique URL and will allow you to easily create a unique rule. If you need to work with the same URL, but you can provide an HTTP header, then that will allow you to create separate rules easily too.'

Comment: Yes, the only downside is that you need to have different urls in thr properties
The idea is to minimize the work, and just proxy the request.

Comment: Could you not work with the name of an already known context, like the name of a class as the identifying part of your URL?